# `nginx_filter_xxx` metrics are missing

Tags: nginx, prometheus

I have:

- activated `nginx_module_vts` (see config below)
- configured and started `nginx_vts_exporter`
- configured `prometheus` to scrape metrics from `nginx_vts_exporter`

I'm able to see `nginx_server_xxx` and `nginx_upstream_xxx` metrics in `prometheus` graph console. However, I can't see `nginx_filter_xxx` metrics.

Also, `filterZones` property is present with full data in response to `/status/format/json`.

**What I'm missing to get `nginx_filter_xxx` metrics in `prometheus`?**

Below is the config of `nginx_module_vts`:

```
http {
  vhost_traffic_status_zone;
  vhost_traffic_status_filter_by_set_key $uri uri::$server_name;
  ...
}

location /status {
  vhost_traffic_status_display;
  vhost_traffic_status_display_format json;
}
```

Example of `/status/format/json` output:

```
{
    "hostName": "ctrl.localdomain",
    ...
    "connections": {
        "active": 4,
        ...
    },
    "sharedZones": {
        "name": "ngx_http_vhost_traffic_status",
        ...
    },
    "serverZones": {
        "nginx-vts.localhost": {
            "requestCounter": 5,
            ...
        },
        "php-fpm.localhost": {
            "requestCounter": 6,
            ...
        },
        ...
        "*": {
            "requestCounter": 18,
            ...
        }
    },
    "filterZones": {
        "uri::nginx-vts.localhost": {
            "/status/format/json": {
                "requestCounter": 5,
                ...
            }
        },
        "uri::php-fpm.localhost": {
            "/status": {
                "requestCounter": 6,
                ...
            }
        },
        ...
    },
    "upstreamZones": {
        "::nogroups": [{
            "server": "127.0.0.1:9000",
            "requestCounter": 6,
            ...
            "inBytes": 624,
        }, {
            "server": "127.0.0.1:49090",
            "requestCounter": 7,
            ...
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 0.6 of `nginx_vts_exporter` I have used doesn't support filter zones. Version 0.7, released on Nov 10th, 2017, supports it.

Please refer to [`nginx_filter_xxx` metrics are missing in `prometheus` graph console](https://github.com/hnlq715/nginx-vts-exporter/issues/40) for more details.